# Ado.net, restaurar la base de datos maestra

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

estoy haciendo un programa para restaurar backups de sql server desde visual basic , pero al momento de restaurar me sale un error , gracias por la ayuda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código para restaurar , la conexion la hago en modulo aparte
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

para restaurar una base de datos en modo de usuario único, lo puedes hacer de dos formas:
- manual (a través del 'Sql Management Studio'): click en el botón derecho sobre la Base de Datos en cuestión, eliges 'Propiedades' y en la columna de la izquierda, 'Opciones'. Verás en la ventana de la derecha la línea de 'Restringir Acceso'. Ahí debes elegir 'SINGLE_USER'
- mediante programación : en el string para instalar el BackUp debes incluir la condición 'SET SINGLE_USER'
Saludos